# How To Smooth Shade Newly Added Mesh To an Already Smooth Shaded Object

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hello I tried to modify and add mesh to an object that already has smooth shading. I can't figure out how to smooth only the new part of the mesh I just added. If I smooth shade the whole object again I will just add unnecessary vertices to the whole object.

Are there any alternatives to splitting the new part of the object mesh into a separate object and smooth shading as a separate object and reintroducing it to the mesh?[image]

[image]

Comment: [Smooth shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html) doesn't add any new geometry rather than edits normals of already existing. You can just select all in Edit mode and choose Smooth shading from Specials menu (shortcut W).

Comment: Are you using`W` > `Shade Smooth` or, `W` > `Smooth`? If you're using just the `Smooth` feature it will move the mesh a little bit possibly giving the appearance of new verts/geometry.

That being said, Mr Zak is right, the `W` > `Shade Smooth` option shouldn't create any new geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the answer after playing around with it for a little bit.

What you need to do is select the new rough mesh you want to smooth in edit 
mode and press P to separate "Selection" as suggested by @Jagredom .

Then with the mesh selected click on the smooth shading button from Object mode.

After this you have to switch to edit mode with the mesh still selected and click on the recalculate normals button under the Shading/UV Tab. This will get the mesh smooth and uniform with the full object.

Then you can rejoin the two objects by clicking on both of them while holding shift and then pressing ctrl + J

[image]

Comment: Recalculating normals and assigning smooth shading can be done without splitting and joining objects, just select all in Edit mode. Note also that topology of the object is quite messy which can lead to the problems you were fixing (normals and shading) because of Ngons and bad edge flow.